# TypeError em python: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python

Bom dia/tarde/noite. Estou tentando criar uma calculadora simples em python, na IDE [Visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/). A seguir segue o script (desculpe por estar em inglês):

```python
import os,sys

#from colored import fg,bg,attr

print("\n\n==>This is the calculator example.")

oneInp = False

def clear():

    os.system('cls')


def calc_simple(n1=0.0, n2=0.0, op=""):
    if n1 == float(n1) and n2 == float(n2):

        if op == "+":

            return float(n1 + n2)

        elif op == "-":

            return float(n1 - n2)

        elif op == "*":

            return float(n1 * n2)

        elif op == "/":

            return float(n1 / n2)

        elif op == "**":

            return float(n1 ** n2)

        elif op == "//":

            return nth_root(n1, n2)

        elif op == "%":

            return float(n1 * (n2 / 100))

        else:

            return "Please type an option..."

    else:

        return "Error"


def nth_root(val=0.0, n=0.0):

    ret = val ** (1 / n)

    return ret


def confirmation():
    confirm = input(">>Are you sure (y/n): ")

    if confirm == "y":

        sys.exit()

    elif confirm == "n":

        clear()

        maincode()

    else:

        print("\n==> Error! \n==> Cause is: " + "The typed value isn't valid." + "\n")
        confirmation()


def shapecheck(inp):

    if inp == "ret":

        return "base"

    elif inp == "sqr":

        return "side"

    elif inp == "par":

        return "base"

    elif inp == "tri":

        return "base"

    elif inp == "tra":

        return "bigger base"

    elif inp == "cir":

        return "radius"


def shapecalc(inp, n1, n2, n3):

    if inp == "ret":

        return n1 * n2

    elif inp == "sqr":

        return n1**2

    elif inp == "par":

        return n1*n2

    elif inp == "tri":

        return (n1*n2)/2

    elif inp == "tra":

        return ((n1+n3)*n2)/2

    elif inp == "cir":

        return n1*3.14


'''def config():

    c1 = np.array(["EnableInt", "Unnecessary"])
    c2 = np.array(["True", ""])

    data = np.column_stack((c1, c2))

    np.savetxt("cfg.cf", data, delimiter=":", fmt="%s")
    txt1 = np.genfromtxt("cfg.cf", delimiter=":", usecols=(0), dtype=None, names=['c1'])
    txt2 = np.genfromtxt("cfg.cf", delimiter=":", usecols=(1), dtype=None, names=['c2'])
    cfg1 = txt2[1]
    cfg1 = np.array_str(cfg1)
    print(cfg1)
    cfg1 = bool(cfg1)
    print(cfg1)
    if cfg1 == True:

        print("Advanced activated!")

    else:

        print("Advanced unactivated!")

'''
def maincode():

    oneInp = False

    try:

        cmd = input("\n>>Choose a command (calc, area, reset, close):")

        if cmd == "calc":

            clear()

            print("------|Calc|------------------\n")

            n1 = float(input("\n>>Type the first operation number:"))

            operation = input(">>Select operation to do (+, -, *, /, **, //, %), without any spaces:")

            op_txt = ""

            if operation == "+":

                op_txt = "second term"

            elif operation == "-":

                op_txt = "subtrahend"

            elif operation == "*":

                op_txt = "factor"

            elif operation == "/":

                op_txt = "divisor"

            elif operation == "**":

                op_txt = "expoent"

            elif operation == "//":

                op_txt = "root index"

            elif operation == "%":

                op_txt = "percentage"

            n2 = float(input(">>Type the {0}:".format(op_txt)))

            clear()

            print("\n-------Result-------\n->%6.2f\n--------------------" % (calc_simple(n1, n2, operation)))

        elif cmd == "area":

            clear()

            print("------|Area|------------------\n")

            oneInp = False

            measure = ""

            measure_tra = ""

            shape = input(">>Select the shape (ret, sqr, par, tri, tra, cir):")

            n1 = 0
            n2 = 0
            n3 = 0

            if shape == "tra":

                measure_tra = "smaller base"

            elif shape == "sqr" or shape == "cir":

                oneInp = True

            else:

                measure_tra = "height"

            measure = shapecheck(shape)

            n1 = float(input(">>Type the {0}:".format(measure)))

            if oneInp == False:

                n2 = float(input(">>Type the height:"))

            if shape == "tra":

                n3 = float(input(">>Type the {0}:".format(measure_tra)))

            clear()

            print("\nArea: {0}".format(shapecalc(shape,n1,n2,n3)))

        elif cmd == "reset":

            clear()

            print("------|Reset|------------------\n")

            reset_app = sys.executable
            clear()
            os.execl(reset_app, reset_app, *sys.argv)

        elif cmd == "close":

            clear()

            print("------|Close|------------------\n")

            confirmation()

        #elif cmd == "config":

            #config()
            #print("\n==>W.I.P.")

        else:

            print(
                "\n==> Error! \n==> Cause is: " + "The typed option doesn't exists." +
                "\n==> Restarting the script...\n")
            maincode()

    except WindowsError:

        print("z")

    except ValueError:

        print("\n==> Error! \n==> Cause is: " + "The typed value isn't valid." + "\n==> Restarting the script...\n")
        maincode()


    except TypeError:

        print("\n==> Error! \n==> Cause is: " + "There isn't any results." + "\n==> Restarting the script...\n")
        maincode()



    maincode()


maincode()
```

Porém, ao executar o código, recebo o seguinte errro:

```
TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

**Por que estou recebendo-o? Poderiam me ajudar?**

Comment: Qual a linha do erro?

Comment: infelizmente só me dá como linha 1, antes recebia erros relacionados à codificação(utf-8, ansi, ascii...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo esta corrompido tenta copiar o código é criar um novo arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado corrigiu o problema!